# Use tag indicating distro, as one prepended into HTML title

Tags: feature-request, tags

I have several questions at the moment, that relate to Parted Magic. A tag for this distro has been created, but as other tags I have used in most of these questions have more followers (as expected) the one with the most followers is prepended to the HTML title.

Presuming others can see the helpfulness of this - Could this be changed, so the HTML title has all distro tags" prioritized over other tags?

Comment: I'll just mention that the tag in the title is entirely for SEO purposes, it's not really expected to be useful for users

Comment: Ah. 1) Would be good if it was for both, 2) Is the distro not found to be as important as the subject with the most followers, 3) If it is to stay for SEO uses, I wonder if there is some JS to remove it from the HTML title.